# luis intent with free form entity handling

Tags: entity, azure-language-understanding, freeform

I am working with Microsoft LUIS and things are going smoothly for well
defined interactions (i.e., closed lists).
I have the use case for a simple feedback bot.
The utterance would look simply like,
  'my feedback is {whatever they say}'.
How would one define things in LUIS for a feedbackIntent such that the extracted entity value is that free form spoken text? Google's api.ai has @sys.any and AWS Lex addresses this fundamental case as well.

Comment: Have you tried creating the intent with utterances where the {whatever they say} part is marked as the feedback? I can imagine it would take several example utterances with labels. How many examples did you try? How varied was the labeled entity?

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues highlighting multiple words in the GUI for some reason. I could have likely tagged things via the REST API. Anyway it looks like the following is working toward the right combination. I added a custom built in entity of Communication.Message and then had utterances like 'the feedback is foobar' where foobar was tagged as a Communication.Message entity. I have variations like 'I think foobar' etc.